# Problems with getting angular 8 to post http request, Postman works fine

Tags: angular, observable, angular-httpclient, subscribe

I'm having some problems getting angular to post my data to the API backend. The API works fine with Postman.

I have a service for the Observable and then I subscribe to it in the component.

What am I trying to do?
I'm trying to post to my backend api/database the firstname, lastname and emaladdress from the html form. If I use Postman it works perfectly, so I don't see that the problem is with the API part. The html has a form in which calls the OnFormSubmit() function. This in turn calls the createArticle(article) function in the article.component.ts, which uses the articleService.createArticle(article) function in the article.service.ts file. When I run the CreateArticle(article) the data/values are passed and returned but in the backend api, they are never written. If I use Postman and add the values for firstname, lastname, and emailaddress it works prefectly.

**EmailsubControler.cs**
This is from the backend api, which works fine with postman

```
//Post an entry to email addresses

  [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string firstname, string lastname, string emailaddress)
    {

    var newemailsub = new EmailSubscriptionModel{ Firstname = firstname, Lastname = lastname, Emailaddress = emailaddress};
    await _context.EmailSub.AddAsync(newemailsub);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(newemailsub);

    }
```

**article.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ArticleService } from './article.service';
import { Article } from './article';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-article',
  templateUrl: './article.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article.component.css']
})
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private articleService: ArticleService, private http: HttpClient) { }


  get firstname() {
     return this.articleForm.get('firstname');
  }

  get lastname() {
     return this.articleForm.get('lastname');
  }

  get emailaddress() {
     return this.articleForm.get('emailaddress');
  }   
  dataSaved = false;
  articleForm: FormGroup;
  allArticles$: Observable<Article[]>;


  time = new Observable<string>((observer: Observer<string>) => {
    setInterval(() => observer.next(new Date().toString()), 1000);
  });



  ngOnInit() {
    this.articleForm = this.formBuilder.group({

      firstname: ['', [ Validators.required ] ],
      lastname: ['', [ Validators.required ] ],
      emailaddress: ['', [ Validators.required ] ]
    });
    // this.loadAllArticles();


  }
  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log('articleafterdataSaved', this.articleForm.value);
    this.dataSaved = false;
    let article = this.articleForm.value;

    this.articleService.getAllArticles().subscribe(articles => {

      this.createArticle(article);

    });
    this.articleForm.reset();
  }

  createArticle(article) {
    console.log('articledataincreatearticle', article);
    this.articleService.createArticle(article)
    .subscribe(

      Response => console.log('insubscribe-returned:', article),
      this.dataSaved = true,
        this.loadAllArticles()
    );

  }



loadAllArticles() {
     this.allArticles$ = this.articleService.getAllArticles();
  }


}
```

**article.ts**
This is the interface

```
export interface Article {
    id?: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    emailaddress: string;
}
```

**article.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Article } from './article';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleService {
  url = "https://localhost:5001/emailsub";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


/*   createArticle(article: Article): Observable<Article> {
    console.log('1inservicearticle', article);
    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');   
    let options = {
        headers: httpHeaders
    };        
    console.log('inservicearticle', article);
    console.log('inservicearticle', this.url);
   // return this.http.post<Article>(this.url, article, options);
    return this.http.post<Article>(this.url, article, options);
  } */

errorHand1: any;



    httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };
  createArticle(article): Observable<Article> {


    console.log('1inservicearticle', article);

    console.log('inservicearticle-article', article);
    console.log('inservicearticle-url', this.url);
    console.log('inservicearticle-JSON', JSON.stringify(article));
   // return this.http.post<Article>(this.url, article, options);
    return this.http.post<Article>(this.url, JSON.stringify(article), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.errorHand1)
    );




     }













  postArticle(article: Article): Observable<HttpResponse<Article>> {
    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
         'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    });    
    console.log('inservice', article.firstname);
    return this.http.post<Article>(this.url, article,
        {
          headers: httpHeaders,
          observe: 'response'

        }

    );
}    


getAllArticles(): Observable<Article[]> {
    return this.http.get<Article[]>(this.url);
}     
}
```

**article.component.html**

```
<h3>Create Article</h3>
<p *ngIf="dataSaved && articleForm.pristine" ngClass = "success">
    Article created successfully.
</p>
<form [formGroup]="articleForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
  <table>
     <tr> 
       <td>firstname: </td>
       <td> 
        <input formControlName="firstname">
        <div *ngIf="firstname.dirty && firstname.errors" class = "error"> 
               <div *ngIf="firstname.errors.required"> 
            firstname required.
           </div>   
            </div>
       </td>
     </tr> 
     <tr> 
       <td>lastname: </td>
       <td> 
          <input formControlName="lastname">
          <div *ngIf="lastname.dirty && lastname.errors" class = "error"> 
          <div *ngIf="lastname.errors.required"> 
            lastname required.
          </div>    
          </div>       
       </td>
     </tr>   
     <tr>
       <td>emailaddress: </td>
       <td> 
          <input formControlName="emailaddress">
          <div *ngIf="emailaddress.dirty && emailaddress.errors" class = "error"> 
            <div *ngIf="emailaddress.errors.required"> 
            emailaddress required.
        </div>             
          </div>       
       </td>
     </tr>       
     <tr>     
       <td colspan="2">
          <button [disabled]="articleForm.invalid">Submit</button>
       </td>
     </tr>     
  </table>  
</form>
<h3>Article Details</h3>
<p *ngFor="let article of allArticles$ | async">
    {{article.id}} | {{article.firstname}} | 
  {{article.lastname}} | {{article.emailaddress}}
</p> 
<div><code>observable|async</code>: Time: {{ time | async }}</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: which function are you calling in your component to "post an article"? This whole question's code is all over the place. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, for taking a look. I'm trying to post to my backend api/database the firstname, lastname and emaladdress from the html form. If I use Postman it works perfectly, so I don't see that the problem is with the API part. The html has a form in which calls the OnFormSubmit() function. This in turn calls the createArticle(article) function in the article.component.ts, which uses the articleService.createArticle(article) function in the article.service.ts file. When I run the CreateArticle(article) the data/values are passed and returned but in the backend api, they are never written.

Comment: What do you mean by: `When I run the CreateArticle(article) the data/values are passed and returned but in the backend api, they are never written.` What is passed to where and what is returned from where. Is something successfully send? Check your browsers developer console and network tab for any errors. This could be a CORS issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks Fridoo, yeah I had already checked the CORS I'm still in development phase so it's set to app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

Comment: So when the createArticle (article) function is called the values in 'article' are passed to the articleService.createArticle(article) and that function then sends the values to the backend http://localhost:5001:emailsub. When I check the database it has added a new 'article' but the firstname, lastname, and emailaddress are blank. The id gets populated, with a number but I have empty values still for the other three. when I check in the subscribe() to see if the values are there , they are. Please run the code it will show you what I mean.

Comment: Ok, so the http post request generally works. But your problem is that your sending and empty object to your backend, right? What do you see in your browsers network analysis page. Is a post request being send without any payload?

Comment: Hi Fridoo, I've added three images, one showing the console, which shows all the times I have tracked the data through the code, the last on the list is whats returned from the observable (i think) The second image is the network, which as you can see it's got the payload and shows a 200 on the status. The third image is Postman, doing a POST which then shows a 200 and the data which has been added to the database, So I cannot see how the backend is the problem as it works fine with Postman. Hope this helps?

Comment: Sorry in answer to your question, Is the post request been sent without any payload, no. and it doesn't look like its sending an empty object( this is where I'm a bit lost) to me it looks like it's got everything it needs and it sends the payload with data and then when I show the data from the response, it's there but nothing has actually got added to the database. I think this is the bit I'm a bit lost with.

Comment: You don't have to use `JSON.stringify` with the HttpClient you can just pass `article` directly. In your subscribe callback you're not logging the response but the article you send with the request `console.log('insubscribe-returned:', article)`. If the http request is send with the correct payload and you get status code 200 everything seems to be fine in your frontend. So I would suggest you check your backend if it adds an empty object to your database. Add log messages to your backend to check whether request from Postman are somehow handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

you're subscribing to `getAllArticles()` in your `onFormSubmit()`, why would you fetch all articles, assign the response to the local `articles` and not use it?
This code is a mess, 1st remove that subscription to `getAllArticles()`, because it's out of context of creating a new article.

```
  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log('articleafterdataSaved', this.articleForm.value);
    this.dataSaved = false;
    let article = this.articleForm.value;  // not sure if that's the correct way to get the values either, but that's for another time.
    this.createArticle(article);
    this.articleForm.reset();
  }
```

Then, I assume, you'd like to load all articles after that's done, for whatever reason.
In your `createArticle()` function you're subscribing to the response of `articleService.createArticle()` and updating `dataSaved` and loading all articles.

```
  createArticle(article) {
    console.log('articledataincreatearticle', article);
    this.articleService.createArticle(article)
    .subscribe(

      Response => console.log('insubscribe-returned:', article),
      this.dataSaved = true,
        this.loadAllArticles()
    );

  }
```

however in `this.loadAllArticles()` you're assigning `allArticles$` to be `articleService.getAllArticles()`

```
loadAllArticles() {
   this.allArticles$ = this.articleService.getAllArticles();
}
```

this of course does nothing unless subscribed.

1st pass:

```
  createArticle(article) {
    console.log('articledataincreatearticle', article);
    this.articleService.createArticle(article).pipe(
      switchMap(response => {
        console.log('insubscribe-returned:', response);
        this.dataSaved = true;
        return this.articleService.getAllArticles();
      }
    .subscribe(articles => this.articles = articles);
  }
```

Here we introduced `switchMap` and `pipe()`
To understand this, you have to look at the map() operator.
Observables are a stream of data. rxjs deals with streams of data.

You can pipe, just like you would in a linux or macos shell, operators and finally subscribe to the result.

Here we switched away from the stream of the `articleService.createArticle()` Observable, did something inside the function (note the {}) and returned a new Observable stream, `articleService.getAllArticles()`.
Then we do whatever with the response of this stream.

2nd pass:

```
onFormSubmit() {
  this.dataSaved = false;
  const article = this.articleForm.value;
  this.articleService.createArticle(article).pipe(
    tap(data => console.log('response from createArticle:', data)),
    tap(data => this.dataSaved = true),
    switchMap(response => this.articleService.getAllArticles()),
    tap(allArticlesData => console.log('all articles response:', allArticlesData)
  ).subscribe(articles => this.articles = articles)
}
```

So we did a bunch of stuff.
We `tap`ped into the stream to log the data.
We also used the `tap` operator to change the `dataSaved` state.
We then switched away from the stream to return a new stream.
Tapped into that stream to console.log values.
And finally assigned the response of that stream to the local articles member variable.

And this is only the tip of the iceberg of issues with your code.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate the time you've taken. Most of this code is from an example I used as I'm trying to learn typescript, angular 8. I'll have a go at changing the code to what you have suggested. Could you help me understand what to type for the subscribe, I really struggle to understand what to put in the subscribe method to retrieve the data and set it to a variable,

Comment: and why does the data exist in the payload and doesn't get added to database, if I debug the api app the variables are 'null' in the controller. It was suggested that the headers are incorrect but as far as I can see its correct? Again thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: I don't even know what language that is .cs files. I use Go on the backend